# Golang reports "context deadline exceeded" with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I wrote an update function, but multiple executions will give the error `context deadline exceeded`.

My function:

```
func Update(link string, m bson.M) {
    configInfo := config.Config()

    // client := GetInstance().client
    // ctx := GetInstance().ctx

    client, _ := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    err := client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("connect error!")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    db := client.Database("test")
    lianjia := db.Collection("test")
    _, err = lianjia.UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"Link": link}, bson.M{"$set": m})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("update error!")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

The output:

```
update error!context deadline exceeded
```

Comment: First: check **all** your errors (`mongo.NewClient()`). Next: `mongo.Connect()` does not block for server discovery. It may return with no error even if you can't connect. Use `Client.Ping()` to verify that the client can connect to the topology.

Comment: @icza Client.ping()  output "client is disconnected",why disconnected?

Comment: You probably can't connect at all. There may be several reasons, e.g. wrong URI, no MongoDB server running etc...

Comment: @icza But I have updated some data.I build MongoDB  by docker with official image .

Comment: Which mongodb version do you use Go mongo driver doesn't support Mongo 2.4 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-1571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change** `mongodb://localhost:27017` **to** `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/`

Comment: Can anyone provide a reason why this is the correct answer? I meant localhost and local IP address are the same unless you host is pointing to a different IP internally

Answer (score 2):

try changing your context timeout say 30 sec

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
ctx := context.Background()
```

Instead of,

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
```

This solved the problem for my issue when I try to develop a REST Back End with MongoDB server

Answer (score -2):

Your URI is wrong, because you were using docker.

If your containers of mongoDB called `mongoContainer`,
you should:

```golang
client, _ := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://mongoContainer"))
```

Comment: Need more explanation why this does not work. What difference does using docker use

Answer (score -2):

This happens sometimes when debugging in GoLand if you have a breakpoint and the program waits then you continue and get this error. If you remove the breakpoint and run the program again it works. At least that's how it was in my case.